# How do you pass a list of ChatRequestMessages to ChatCompletionsOptions in the constructor()?

Tags: azure-openai

In the example below, the call to GetChatCompletionAsync works correctly if I initialize the ChatCompletionsOptions.Messages in the "new ChatCompletionsOptions() {}" but not if I pass (what I believe is) the same list of messages in the constructor. I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. Can anyone show me a code snippet of the correct way to send an IList to the constructor of ChatCompletionsOptions?

```
          List<ChatRequestMessage> m = new List<ChatRequestMessage>(){
                      new ChatRequestSystemMessage("You are a helpful assistant. You will talk like a pirate."),
                      new ChatRequestAssistantMessage("Arrrr! Of course, me hearty! What can I do for ye?"),
                      new ChatRequestUserMessage("How does one care for a parrot?"),
                  };


      //This works
      var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
      {
          DeploymentName = "MyGPT35Turbo", // Use DeploymentName for "model" with non-Azure clients
          Messages =
                  {
                      new ChatRequestSystemMessage("You are a helpful assistant. You will talk like a pirate."),
                      new ChatRequestAssistantMessage("Arrrr! Of course, me hearty! What can I do for ye?"),
                      new ChatRequestUserMessage("How does one care for a parrot?"),
                  }
      };

      ////This doesn't
      //var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions(m)
      //{
      //    DeploymentName = "MyGPT35Turbo"
      //};


      Response<ChatCompletions> response = await client
          .GetChatCompletionsAsync(chatCompletionsOptions);
```

Comment: The only  property that I don't see created when I pass the messages in the constructor is the TokenSelectionBiases (which is read only). So, I'm pretty stuck. I need to be able to create the message list on the fly and pass it to the ChatCompletionsOptions.

Comment: Though I still don't know how to use the command line, you can use this:             chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatRequestSystemMessage("You are a helpful assistant. You will talk like a pirate."));
            chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatRequestAssistantMessage("Arrrr! Of course, me hearty! What can I do for ye?"));
            chatCompletionsOptions.Messages.Add(new ChatRequestUserMessage("How does one care for a parrot?"));